# Reason for the names "Class Adapter" and "Object Adapter"

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Adapter pattern implemented with inheritance is called "class adapter" while one implemented with composition is called "object adapter". Is there a conceptual reason behind "class" and "object" adjectives here?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

As far as I can tell the reason for this is simply to differentiate the two different adaptor pattern designs.

When this pattern is implemented using inheritance, there are no objects yet.  It is strictly a class thing.

When the adaptor pattern is implemented with composition, an object (instance of a class) is used. So it is referred to as an object adaptor pattern.

Both designs achieve the same goal but are implemented slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks! I did think about that. However even in the 'object adapter' case we need to specify the class (type) of the object beforehand. Of course we can use a base class there, but then we would be using another 'class adapter' there.

Comment: Keep in mind design patterns should be language agnostic and not all languages would need a class type.  However, I think the main idea is that "object adaptor" is not implemented using inheritance while "class adaptor" is.